# What does "le" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, pronombres

Another sample sentence I came across:

> Le añadiremos aceite al motor cuando lo necesite.

What does the pronoun **Le** refer to, and is it necessary?  **aceite** o **el motor**? (Or something else I'm not seeing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary.

> Añadiremos aceite al motor cuando lo necesite.

has the same meaning of

> (Nosotros) (le) añadiremos aceite al motor cuando *lo* necesite.

`Añadir` is transitive. `Aceite` is the direct objet and `motor` stands for the indirect. `Le` is a pronoun referring to `el motor`. According to the [RAE rules for pronouns](http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo) we use "*le*" as a pronoun referring to the indirect object.

If you had been talking about the oil then you could have said

> **Lo** añadiremos cuando el motor lo necesite.

Since we use *"lo"* as a pronoun for the direct object.

Notice that in the same sentence of your example you are using "lo" to refer to the oil, just because in that case the meaning is

> El motor necesita aceite

and `aceite` will be the direct complement ("El motor **lo** necesita").